# DNN7 DesktopModules do not load

Tags: html, module, default, dotnetnuke-7

Fresh install of DNN 7.4.2

Anything under the site's DesktopModules folder does not look like it loaded.

How can I get those items like HTML, Journal, SocialGroups, etc to load?

My issue is that on a new page, I can't add an HTML module - that module, and all others from that directory are not one of the available items to add to a page.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the Extensions page, edit one of the missing modules, and check to see that it has been assigned to the portal in questions.

Comment: Thanks, but precisely because they don’t show in the extension page (they really don’t even show up anywhere - not even on disk under the website folder) u can’t affect any change to them. They do show up under the source directory, and I don’t know how to ‘install’ them in the website subdirectory

Comment: Can anyone share a link to the actual production install of 7.4.2? I got the version I’m using from the full repo from the branch marked as 7.4.2 release. It obviously doesn’t act correctly

Comment: If the modules do not show on the Host, Extensions page and they are not in the Desktop Modules folder, then thhey haven't been installed.

Check the portals/_default/logs folder for a file with install in the file name.  That is a record of what happened when you did the install.  Maybe there is a clue there.

There should have been a number of modules installed.  On the extensions page, click the Available Modules link to see if there are modules that weren't installed.

Comment: Is there a guide or instruction steps on how to install the ones from the source DesktopMidules directory that are not in the hosted website DesktopModules directory?